# Using a macro to merge cells in a row and then move to next row

Tags: excel, vba, merge

Good Afternoon.

I need help writing a macro that needs to look at the value in cell F5 and if it meets a certain criteria it merges cells F5:O5 and then moves onto f6 and repeats for 50 rows.

I cannot post an image as I am a new user unfortunately. If the cell in column F is equal to "Empty to 0" I need to change the value to "Empty to Kettering" and merge to column O and them move to row 6.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This macro will process 50 rows starting with row #5:

```
Sub Mergee()
    Dim I As Long
    For I = 5 To 54
        If Cells(I, "F").Text = "Empty to 0" Then
            Cells(I, "F").Value = "Empty to Kettering"
            Range(Cells(I, "F"), Cells(I, "O")).Merge
        End If
    Next I
End Sub
```

To change the number of rows, change the **54**.